# What is the best method the detect if user is online / offline ? PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication, logout

I want to add `online/offline` system to my project, but I'm confused with the best method to do it.

On login and log out, it's easy to update the column `online` on the database with `false` or `true`

User Table:

```
---------------------------
| ID |   Email   | online |
---------------------------
| 1  | test@g.co |    0   |
---------------------------
| 2  |  te@g.be  |    1   |
---------------------------
```

But the problem is when the user closes the browser without sign out, how I can update the online column with `false`?

So, I thought by using an ajax running every 4 or 5 min, to call a function checking if users stay online or no.

But I think that this method is not professional, and it can be heavy on the website (to run a script) can make the website slow.

Is there any best method to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

> But I think that this method is not professional

It's a standard approach.

> and it can be heavy on the website (to run a script) can make the website slow.

One HTTP request every 5 minutes to call a simple "I'm alive" script is **not** going to be remotely heavy.

Comment: but to call of HTTP request it's not one, but it's related with the number of visitors if they're 1000 users, so it 1000 HTTP request every 5 minutes, for that I'm confused and I don't know if that can make the website slow or not

Comment: And how many *other* (mostly much heavier) HTTP requests will those 1000 users be making while they are active on the site? A 5 minute keep alive script is a drop in the ocean.

Comment: A good analogy sir, Thanks for your reply sir